# sockets.io on() not receiving first emit from server

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I am building this collaborative whiteboard with multiple rooms.( Each url is a different one) . My problem is that when I draw lines on 1st window nothing happen in the other ones but as soon as I draw in the other one then its works. I need to draw in any other window to 'activate it' and then the connection seem to be working fine.

Here is the server side code:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    socket.on('room', function(room){
        socket.join(room);
        socket.on('drawing', function(drawObj){
           socket.to(room).emit('drawing', drawObj);
      });
    });
```

and here is the client side portion:

```
socket.on('drawing', function(drawObj){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(drawObj.prevX, drawObj.prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(drawObj.currX, drawObj.currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
 });
```

Thank you very much. I am also not sure about my room implementation, any feedback is welcomed. Thanks
`

Answer (score 0):

actually never mind, dumb mistake on my side I was not communicating the room before drawing. If anyone has comment on the room implementation though, any feedback is welcomed:)